# Deploy to GitHub Pages using Flutter Web not working

Tags: flutter, github-pages

Deploying to GitHub Pages using actions with Flutter Web is not working.

I just keep getting a blank page.

Any help appreciated.

I am using and the following pipeline on GitHub Actions

[image]

```
name: Deploy to GitHub Pages

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

# Deploy to the github-pages environment


jobs:  
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Flutter
        uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          channel: stable
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: flutter pub get
        working-directory: ${{env.working-directory}}
      - name: Build web app
        run: flutter build web
        working-directory: ${{env.working-directory}}

      - name: Upload Pages artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v2
        with:
          path: build/web/

      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v2
```

Comment: Any errors your are seeing when the action is performed?

Comment: Hey matey patatey, it's resolved now. Thanks for inquiring though

Answer (score 1):

**FIXED**.

The solution for me was to comment out the following line of code in the *yourprojectname*/web/index.html

[image]

After pushing this to GitHub - the build started working and deploying **successfully** to **GitHub Pages**. Hopefully this works for anyone else who is stuck.

After navigating to my page it worked:

*yourreponame*.github.io/*yourprojectname*/

Good luck and Kia Kaha.